# Redis: Set different time to live for methods annotated with @Cacheable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I have a set of cached methods that look somewhat like this:

```
@Cacheable(value = "myCacheName", keyGenerator = "myKeyGenerator")
public Product getProduct(ProductRequest request) {
    // ...
}
```

And I need to set different time to live (expiration interval) for objects returned by these methods.

**Problem:** According to [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis.repositories.expirations), the offered way is using `@RedisHash(timeToLive=…​)` or `@TimeToLive` annotations on the return type of the methods. However, I don't want to pollute my domain classes with caching related logic. In addition, some of my methods return strings or objects of classes which I can not modify. I would prefer to implement it in a more configurable way. There is also a configuration property called `spring.cache.redis.time-to-live`, but it applies the same time-to-live in all places.

**Question:** Is there a way to specify time to live/expiration interval on the method level? Or generally, how to implement it in a more elegant way?

Comment: If you have limited cache names, you can setting TTL for each cache name by configuring `CacheManager` bean. It would be great if SDR allows config TTL as property of `@Cacheable`

Comment: Did you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181768/can-i-set-a-ttl-for-cacheable

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn I do have limited cache names. Could you please elaborate on the solution.

Comment: @OleksandrShpota You can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054774/how-to-configure-different-ttl-for-each-redis-cache-when-using-cacheable-in-spr). The idea is to configure different cache manager with different TTL.

Answer (score 9):

Hi if you want to use only Spring annotations one way to do this is the following.
`@CacheConfig` annotation allows you to define specific CacheManager to use further more the `@Cacheable` annotation also allows defining cacheManager

```
@CacheConfig(cacheNames="myCacheName",cacheManager="timeoutCacheManager")
class ProductReader {

    @Cacheable(value = "myCacheName", keyGenerator = "myKeyGenerator")
   public Product getProduct(ProductRequest request) {
      // ...
   }

}


@Bean
public CacheManager timeoutCacheManager(RedisTemplate redisTemplate) {
    RedisCacheManager cacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate);
    cacheManager.setDefaultExpiration(mytimeToLive);
    return cacheManager;
}
```

Here is also a fragment of a more extensive cache configuration that is resulting again in a CacheManager. This time it configures multiple regions:

```
@Bean (name="cacheManager")
public RedisCacheManager cacheManager(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    RedisCacheConfiguration conf_ready_info = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
            .entryTtl(Duration.ofMillis(50000));

    RedisCacheConfiguration conf_base_info = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
            .entryTtl(Duration.ofMillis(60000));

    Map<String, RedisCacheConfiguration> cacheConfigurations = new HashMap<String, RedisCacheConfiguration>();
    cacheConfigurations.put("base_info", conf_base_info);
    cacheConfigurations.put("ready_info", conf_ready_info);

    return RedisCacheManager.RedisCacheManagerBuilder.fromConnectionFactory(connectionFactory)
            .withInitialCacheConfigurations(cacheConfigurations).build();
}
```

I took the last example from:
[set expire key at specific time when using Spring caching with Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51660160/set-expire-key-at-specific-time-when-using-spring-caching-with-redis)

Using only `@Cacheable(value = "myCacheName", keyGenerator = "timeoutCacheManager")`

Comment: RedisCacheManager not have setDefaultExpiration method! i'm using spring data redis 2.5.7