# Redis - Multiple caches with different TTL

Tags: java, spring, redis, memcached, spring-cache

I'm working with Java 17 / Spring and this **application.yml** is working well.
The problem is I need a different time-to-live for each cache:

10s for cache1

20s for cache2

```
spring:
  cache:
    cache-names: cache1, cache2
    type: redis
    redis:
      time-to-live: 10s
      key-prefix: rop
      use-key-prefix: true
      cache-null-values: false
      enable-transaction-support: false
  data:
    redis:
      url:redis://localhost:6379
```

I already tried some variations of this file, but none worked.
any clue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I've found an solution at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56564503/redis-set-different-time-to-live-for-methods-annotated-with-cacheable)

Here is the code that help me out:

```
@Bean (name="cacheManager")
public RedisCacheManager cacheManager(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    RedisCacheConfiguration conf_1_info = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
            .entryTtl(Duration.ofMinutes(10));

    RedisCacheConfiguration conf_2_info = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
            .entryTtl(Duration.ofMinutes(30));

    Map<String, RedisCacheConfiguration> cacheConfigurations = new HashMap<String, RedisCacheConfiguration>();
    cacheConfigurations.put("cache1", conf_1_info);
    cacheConfigurations.put("cache2", conf_2_info);

    return RedisCacheManager.RedisCacheManagerBuilder.fromConnectionFactory(connectionFactory)
            .withInitialCacheConfigurations(cacheConfigurations).build();
}
```

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.