# Redis cache in spring boot 3 config TTL and prefix name for cache but not active

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I am using Spring Boot 3 with redis cache. I want to use redis to cache with prefix name and TTL to auto-release cache but it doesn't active.

pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
                <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
        <artifactId>redisson-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.21.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

RedissonConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
@Slf4j
public class RedissonConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.data.redis.mode}")
    private String mode;

    @Bean
    public RedisCacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration() {
        return RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                .entryTtl(Duration.ofMinutes(1))
                .prefixCacheNameWith("prefix-name-");
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisCacheManager cacheManager(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return RedisCacheManager.create(connectionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public RedissonClient redissonClient(RedisProperties redisProperties) {
        Config config = new Config();
        config.useSingleServer()
                    .setAddress("redis://" + redisProperties.getHost() + CashConstants.COLON + redisProperties.getPort())
                    .setPassword(redisProperties.getPassword())
                    .setTimeout((int) redisProperties.getTimeout().toMillis())
                    .setConnectTimeout((int) redisProperties.getConnectTimeout().toMillis())
                    .setKeepAlive(true);
        return Redisson.create(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory(RedissonClient redissonClient) {
        return new RedissonConnectionFactory(redissonClient);
    }
}
```

Use @Cacheable

```
    @Override
    @Cacheable(value = "profile", key = "#id")
    public Optional<Model> getData(String id) {
        // code logic
    }
```

My expect:

1. redis cache name will be **prefix-name-profile** but actual only is **profile**
2. redis cache will be release after 1 minute but it still alive

[image: redis-cache]

Thanks for your helping.

Answer (score 0):

I find a answer resolve my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53295072/4768616

My code edit and will run as my expect

```
    @Value("${custom.redis.prefix}")
    private String prefixCache;

    @Value("${custom.redis.cache-name}")
    private List<String> caches;

    @Value("${custom.redis.cache-ttl}")
    private int cacheTtl;

    public RedisCacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration() {
        return RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                .entryTtl(Duration.ofMinutes(cacheTtl))
                .disableCachingNullValues()
                .prefixCacheNameWith(prefixCache);
    }

    @Bean(name = "cacheManager")
    public RedisCacheManager cacheManagerCustom(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        Map<String, RedisCacheConfiguration> cacheConfigurations
                = caches.stream().collect(HashMap::new, (m, v) -> m.put(v, cacheConfiguration()), HashMap::putAll);

        return RedisCacheManager.RedisCacheManagerBuilder.fromConnectionFactory(connectionFactory)
                .cacheDefaults(cacheConfiguration())
                .withInitialCacheConfigurations(cacheConfigurations)
                .transactionAware()
                .build();
    }
```